Parallelizability and homotopy type
Suppose $M$ is a smooth, compact manifold with nonempty boundary, and that $\operatorname{int}(M)=M-\partial M$ is a parallelizable manifold. Then is it true that $M$ is also parallelizable? Actually I am reading Milnor's book Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces, and in Theorem 5.1 it is shown that a certain open manifold $F_\theta$ is parallelizable, and later in Remark 8.7 it is written that $\overline{F_\theta}$, which is a manifold with $\operatorname{int}(\overline{F_\theta})=F_\theta$, is parallelizable.
Maybe this argument seems to work: Attaching a collar to $M$, we can actually embed $M$ in $\operatorname{int}(M)$, so then the parallelizability of $M$ follows from that of $\operatorname{int}(M)$. Does this have no problem?
I am also curious about the more general question: if two smooth manifolds have the same homotopy type, then does the parallelizability of one implies that of the other one?

As for your last question, think about Moebius band; is it homotopy equivalent to a parallelizable manifold?

@MoisheKohan It is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ which is parallelizable. But is the tangent bundle of the Moebius band nontrivial?

Is a parallelizable manifold orientable?

@MoisheKohan Oh I see, thanks!
